# fetch aggregate value along with data

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sum

I have a table with the following fields

```
 ID,Content,QuestionMarks,TypeofQuestion

 350, What is the symbol used to represent Bromine?,2,MCQ 
 758,What is the symbol used to represent Bromine? ,2,MCQ
 2425,What is the symbol used to represent Bromine?,3,Essay
 2080,A quadrilateral has four sides, four angles  ,1,MCQ
 2614,A circular cone has a curved surface area of ,2,MCQ
 2520,Two triangles have sides 5 cm, 11 cm, 2 cm . ,2,MCQ
 2196,Life supporting process mediated by water?   ,2,Essay
```

I would like to get random questions where total marks is an input number.
For example if I say 25, the result should be all the random questions whose Sum(QuestionMarks) is 25(+/-1)

Is this really possible using a SQL

```
select content,id,questionmarks,sum(questionmarks) from quiz_question
group by content,id,questionmarks;
```

Expected Input 25
Expected Result (Sum of Question Marks =25)

**Update**:
How do I ensure I get atleast 2 Essay Type Questions (this is just an example) I would extend this for other conditions. Thank you for all the help

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Answer (score 2):

S-Man's cumulative sum is the right approach.  For your logic, though, I think you want to get up to the first row that is 24 or more.  That logic is:

```
where total - questionmark < 24
```

If you have enough questions, then you could get *exactly* 25 using:

```
with q25 as (
      select *
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(questionmark) over (order by random()) as running_questionmark
            from t
           ) t
      where running_questionmark < 25
     )
select q.ID, q.Content, q.QuestionMarks, q.TypeofQuestion
from q25 q
union all
(select t.ID, t.Content, t.QuestionMarks, t.TypeofQuestion
 from t cross join
        (select sum(questionmark) as questionmark_25 from q25) x
 where not exists (select 1 from q25 where q25.id = t.id) 
 order by abs(questionmark - (25 - questionmark_25))
 limit 1
)
```

This selects questions up to 25 but not at 25.  It then tries to find one more to make the total 25.

Comment: Really nice idea! :)

Comment: How do I ensure I get atleast 2 Essay Type Questions (this is just an example) I would extend this for other conditions. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: @stackoverflowrohit . . . This answers the question that you originally asked -- and has been answered twice.  If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing, `questionmark` is of type `integer`. Then you want to get some records in random order whose `questionmark` sum is not more than `25`:

You can use the consecutive `SUM()` window function. The order is random. The consecutive `SUM()` adds every current value to the previous sum. So, you could filter where `SUM() <= <your value>`:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6f5a8c5a2c530c7e13e50d89d696fd69)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        SUM(questionmark) OVER (ORDER BY random()) as total
    FROM
        t
)s 
WHERE total <= 25
```

**Note**:

This returns a records list with no more than 25, but as close as possible to it with an random order.

To find an **exact** match of your value is some sort of combinatorical problem which shouldn't be solved in a database. Especially when there's a random factor. What if your current SUM is `22` and the next randomly chosen value is `4`. Would you retry maybe until infinity to randomly find a `value = 3`? Or are you trying to remove an already counted record with `value = 1`?

Comment: I need to get random questions whose sum of QuestionMarks is 25

Comment: Edited. Does this fit your problem?